# Firebase Database won't allow a substring of user email

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to write rules in firebase for an app I am making.  The way I have my data structured for my users is like this

```
users
   -username (a substring of the users email)
       -all other data
```

where the username is a substring from the text before the period in an email address (for example, johnsmith@gmail.com's username would be johnsmith@gmail).  I am trying to write some rules based around this format, but I keep getting this error

`Error saving rules - Line 8: Key names can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]" (unbound names start with "$")`

This is the JSON code I am attempting to use for this rule

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read":"auth.uid != null",
    ".write":false,
    "users": {
      "$substringBefore(auth.token.email,' ')": {
        ".write": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone explain how I can get it to accept the users email substring for the username node?

Comment: Since email addresses can contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", and/or "]", I'm wondering how you intend this to work. (Of those, "." is really common, your example user can also get email as "john.smith@gmail.com" without changing anything on his part, gmail silently ignores the dots in the localpart.)

Comment: @CupcakeProtocol I didn't think about it like that and now I see major flaws in that system.  What would be a better way to organize the users?

Comment: I'm all for letting users pick their own usernames. But that has it's own complexity.

Comment: Why are you not using their Firebase Auth uid as the key here?  This pattern is very well documented and easy to implement. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security

Comment: @DougStevenson I created the database schema when I didn't know about the uid because I was new to firebase, I was trying to avoid having to restructure my code but it seems as if I'll have to do that in order to allow sufficient security rules.